# How to prove $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^n |1-\exp(2\pi k i\alpha)|=0$

Tags: limits, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I wonder how to show the following limit inferior ($\alpha$ is an irrational number)

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^n |1-\exp(2\pi k i\alpha)|=0.$$

Intuitively this is quite true since $\{\exp(2\pi k i\alpha)\}$ is [uniformly distributed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441927/do-the-multiples-of-an-irrational-number-modulo-1-cover-the-unit-interval-unifor) on the unit circle at origin (since [elementary proofs](https://mathoverflow.net/a/109158/64462) are known, please feel free to use this result). When $n$ is large, $|1-\exp(2\pi k i\alpha)|$ is at most $2$ but can frequently be close to zero. So the product will be frequently close to zero (MatLab experiment also shows the same phenomenon). But how do we make this into a rigorous argument?

Another result we can consider using is the Huiwitz's theorem, which states that there are infinitely many relatively prime integers $a, q$ such that

$$|\alpha-\frac{a}{q}|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}.$$

Let $(a_n),(q_n)$ be such a sequence with $q_n \to \infty$ and $\alpha=\frac{a_n}{q_n}+\beta$ and $|\beta|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}.$ I speculate that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{q_n} |1-\exp(2\pi k i\alpha)|=0$$

(of course you don't have to use my idea to answer the question I asked)

Here is the reasoning for the result of [limsup](https://mathoverflow.net/a/237807/64462), which might help.

Answer (score -1):

Let $a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n|1 - \exp(2\pi i \alpha k)|$

So

$$ a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n\sqrt{(\cos(2\pi\alpha k) - 1)^2 + \sin^2(2\pi\alpha k)}$$
$$ a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n\sqrt{2 - 2\cos^2(2\pi\alpha k)} $$
$$ a_n = 2^{\frac n2} \prod_{k=1}^n|\sin(2\pi\alpha k)|$$

Does this lead anywhere?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the mistake

Comment: this is trivial and actually the current form is wrong as $a_n = 2^n \prod_{k=1}^n|\sin(\pi\alpha k)|$ as your computation is quite incorrect ($2\cos^2(2\pi\alpha k)$ is actually $2\cos(2\pi\alpha k)$ and one needs to use the double angle formula)